# how retrieve inserted data when submit in same view page without refresh in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have product page, here both add product form and product list.
I just want when I add a product it will immediate display in product list content in same page. my problem is,  it's not display recent product until i refresh.

its may be top to bottom problem (select query then insert query). i can solve this scratch style(without codeigniter). but how codeigniter  do that. my controller's  product() is

```
    public function product(){
    $data['title'] = 'Product'; // Capitalize the first letter
    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product', 'Product', 'required|min_length[7]|max_length[7]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('purchase_price', 'Purchase Price', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sell_price', 'Sell Price', 'required|numeric');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
                 $data['products']=$this->admin_model->show_product();//my select query
             $this->load->view('admin_panel/product',$data);
    }
    else
    {
            $data['products']=$this->admin_model->show_product();//my select query
            $this->load->view('admin_panel/product',$data);
            $this->admin_model->add_product();//my insert query
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: Where are your post variables? $this->input->post('product'), $this->input->post('purchase_price'), $this->input->post('sell_price')

Comment: this is my add_product model  public function add_product(){
  $data=array(
   'product_name'=>$this->input->post('product'),
   'product_purchase_price'=>$this->input->post('purchase_price'),
   'product_sell_price'=>$this->input->post('sell_price'),
   'category_id'=>$this->input->post('my_items_dropdown')
  );
  return $this->db->insert('product',$data);
 }

Comment: Interesting. You could also do a Select based on $this->db->insert_id();. Which is just the ID of your newly added product. See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: may be insert_id() means inserted last id. I need all data without refreshing

Answer (score 1):

Insert and retrieve data together is same view

```
public function category1()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('category_settings'));
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
            if ($this->form_validation->run('submit') == FALSE) {

             //Display records 

            $data['category1'] = $this->category_model->display_category1();
                    $this->load->view('admin/add_category1',$data);
                } else {

                  //Add record

                    $this->add_category1();

                }
            }



public function add_category1()
    {
          //$parent_category = $this->input->post('parent_category');
          $data    = array(
            'parent_category_name' => $this->input->post('parent_category')
           );
          $insert_category1 = $this->category_model->add_category1($data);

          if($insert_category1){
              $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'Category Added Successfully');
              redirect(base_url('admin/category/category1'));
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry, I mistake.

top to bottom style not  *select query then insert query*. its  **insert query then select query**

so code should

```
else
{
        $this->admin_model->add_product();//my insert query 
        $data['products']=$this->admin_model->show_product();//my select query
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/product',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use jQuery to do this, PHP/CodeIgniter cannot dynamically update a page alone. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/; there are many tutorials available on http://net.tutsplus.com/ and similar sites.